# Native music listening app

Tags: google-pixel

I have just made the transition to android(Google Pixel) and HATE having to keep saying no to the Google Play music offer (sort of like Apple Music). It is as though I have bought a cheap product. OR Is there any way to stop the relentless ads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think there's any dedicated option for stopping this ads inside Google Play Music, but you can change the settings of your Google Ad ID from Google Settings app or Settings>> Google>> Ads

OR

ROOT YOUR PHONE THEN use AdAway!!

Comment: … or use a decent (open-source) music player :) There [are some in my lists](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_music_jukeboxen).

Comment: Musixmatch could be a good choice.

Comment: Based on above, all "good choices" are rather opinion based. If OP wants to go that path, there are better places – see: [Where to ask for app recommendations?](https://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/2060/16575) :)

Comment: You can try [Lucky Patcher](https://lucky-patcher.netbew.com) if you have root.